# Claves primarias en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla idioma con los siguientes valores:

```
Schema::create('idiomas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('idioma');
        $table->string('nivel_hablado');
        $table->string('nivel_escrito');
        $table->string('titulo_oficial');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

La variable 'idioma' es cual es el idioma (inglés, aleman, japones, etc) mientras que 'user_id' es el usuario de la base de datos.
Quiero que ambas variables sean primarias, lo cual hara que puedan coincidir en 2 filas el user_id o el idioma, pero nunca podra haber 2 filas con exactamente el mismo idioma y user_id.
¿Como logro eso?

Edito: Ya he visto que mi tabla ya tiene una clave primaria, el id. La historia es que quiero que tanto idioma como user_id deben ser unicos, pero no individualmente, sino que no puede haber el mismo idioma para el mismo usuario, pero puede un usuario tener varios idiomas y un idioma estar en varios usuarios.

En MySQL se lograria así:

```
CREATE TABLE idiomas(
id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
idioma varchar(25) NOT NULL,
user_id varchar(2) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE `idioma_usuario_uidx` (`idioma`,`user_id`));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este nuevo problema que planteas esta es mi respuesta.
En la documentación tenés todos los distintos tipos de indices y como los podés generar. Vos estás necesitando un indice unico compuesto y eso es como el indice compuesto que te puse en la anterior respuesta solo que en lugar de ser indice primario en este caso es un indice unico. De esta forma vas a poder tener por cada usuario tantos idiomas como desees.

```
Schema::create('idiomas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('idioma');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    $table->unique(['user_id', 'idioma']);
});
```

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación [Creating Indexes (Creando Indices)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes) para entender un poco mejor.
Saludos y espero haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Vale, ahora esta mejor esto.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de tener una tabla `users`, una tabla `idiomas` y otra table `idioma_user`. Esta ultima para ralacionar los idiomas disponibles con los usuarios.

Te propongo lo siguiente:

**Migraciones**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('idiomas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('nombre');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('idioma_user', function (Blueprint $table) { // tiene que ir en orden alfabetico y en singular al igual que los nombres de los modelos correspondientes
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->unsignedInteger('idioma_id');
    $table->foreign('idioma_id')->references('id')->on('idiomas');
    $table->string('nivel_hablado');
    $table->string('nivel_escrito');
    $table->string('titulo_oficial');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->index(['user_id', 'idioma_id']); // con esto no podrá haber un usuario con 2 idiomas. solo puede existir esta combinación.
});
```

**Modelo User**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function idioma()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\IdiomaUser::class);
    }
}
```

**Modelo Idioma**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Idioma extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(\App\IdiomaUser::class);
    }
}
```

**Modelo IdiomaUser**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IdiomaUser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'idioma_id', 'nivel_hablado', 'nivel_escrito', 'titulo_oficial'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function idioma()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Idioma::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Con esto podés por ejemplo hacer:

```
$user = auth()->user();
dd($user->idioma, $user->idioma->nivel_hablado);
```

También podrías obtener el listado de usuarios por idioma

```
$idioma = Idioma::find(1);
dd($idioma->users);
```

Comment: Es interesante, pero en este ejemplo los idiomas son una variable independiente. No estan dentro de una tabla. ¿No hay una forma de decir directamente a Laravel que un conjunto de variables son clave primaria?

Comment: Claro que se puede, en mi ejemplo puse un index compuesto simple, pero ese index puede ser primary key. `$table->primary(['user_id', 'idioma']);`. Mirá la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#indexes

Comment: Si pongo por ejemplo $table->primary(['user_id', 'idioma']); me salta este mensaje de error al hacer la migración: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `idiomas` add primary key `idiomas_user_id_idioma_primary`(`user_id`, `idioma`))

Comment: borraste el id increments?

Comment: acabo de hacer una prueba y a mi me funciona

Comment: ¿Borrar el id? Cierto que es la clave primaria, aunque se me hace raro por ser el indice...

Comment: he editado mi pregunta para aclarar algunas cosas.